# Merging worksheets starting with the name "Index"

Tags: excel, vba

Goodmorning guys,

I'm having problems to find an VBA code to merge worksheets from multiple excel files to one excel file. I got the following VBA code:

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook

fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

    If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
        countFiles = 0
        countSheets = 0

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

        For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
            countFiles = countFiles + 1

            Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

            For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                countSheets = countSheets + 1
                wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
            Next

            wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Next

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If

Else


      MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If
End Sub
```

What i would like to have is that I only want to merge the worksheets named "Index" instead of merging ALL the worksheets of the excel-files I select. Is there an solution for this? Could you guys please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have this line:

```
                wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
```

Update it to add a condition to check the name, like this:

```
                If wksCurSheet.Name = "Index" then wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
```

If you only want the counter to increment when it finds such as sheet, wrap both lines in the new condition, like this:

```
                If wksCurSheet.Name = "Index" then 
                    countSheets = countSheets + 1
                    wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
                End If
```

Comment: Hey ed2, 

Thanks!! That did it for me :)

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer worked for you, please consider marking it as correct and useful so that future visitors can see the trail and be helped also. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thanks!